# how to run 'current' or 'multiple' SQLs in LINQPad

Tags: sql, oracle-12c

I've search around and can't find what I'm looking for here. Hoping a SuperUser can guide me.

I'm working with Oracle inside LINQPad. Just basic SQL. And I can't figure out how to get the app to run multiple queries at once.

Like:

```
SELECT 'STEVE1' "BOB" FROM DUAL;

SELECT 'STEVE2' "JEN" FROM DUAL;
```

I'm expecting to get two results tabs/blocks but LINQPad isn't splitting the queries and Oracle is complaining with **ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended error**.

Any tips on getting LINQPad to see these as two queries and to split them for Oracle properly? (like the official clients do?). Thanks so much.

Comment: There should be a comma (`,`) between the two columns `STEVE1` and `BOB` (see e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp). Or does Oracle SQL allow to ignore it? May that's the actual issue?

Comment: 'STEVE1' is the value I'm aliasing AS "BOB". Oracle uses ' as string and " as column name and can assume the AS. The individual SQLs are fine. I just can't get both to run at once with two results blocks